# How to make an image glide in javascript?

Tags: javascript

How to make an image glide in javascript? I am trying to make an image that will glide in javascript without css animations!

Comment: What do you mean by gliding?

Comment: I mean going from a place to another, smoothly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by toggling class. Add a default style with transition duration property.

```
.image {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  transition-duration: 2s;
}

.move {
  left: calc(100% - 200px);
}
```

In JavaScript toggle the class (Here I'm toggling when a click event occur).

```
function move () {
  const img = document.querySelector('.image')
  img.classList.toggle("move")
}
```

I have made a codepen project [here](https://codepen.io/jegatheesprana/pen/bGaQzoL).